# Error while installing Homebrew on Lion

Tags: macos, xcode, error, homebrew

I started installing Homebrew on my Mac Lion v10.7.4 but got the following error.

```
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
Failed during: Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error. init -q
```

I ran the following command as mentioned on Homebrew website:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I tried to search for solutions for this error but nothing relevant came up. How can this be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Xcode command line tools?

Comment: @Mark No, I don't have it installed. Homebrew homepage didn't mention it on the homepage and I assumed that it wouldn't need any additional package to work. Just looked up Homebrew wiki and it indeed says that Xcode command line tool is required. Thank you very much! Downloading it right now and will report back after trying it.

Comment: @Mark Installing Xcode command line tools solved the problem. Thank you again. Though not sure how to mark your comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the Xcode command line tools installed. See Homebrew [installation page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation).